# Why count doesn't work for this list?(in python)

Tags: python, numpy, import

In the following code the result in "countOf1" is 0 instead of 12. What is the reason and how can i solve it?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.matrix(np.arange(12).reshape((1, 12)))
x[:,:]=1
countOf1=(x.tolist()).count(1)
```

Comment: Did you look at the value of `x.tolist()`?

Comment: Why don't you do `np.count_nonzero(x == 1)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you convert that into a list with [`tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html?highlight=tolist#numpy.ndarray.tolist) you're getting a subset of a list. Meaning this is your `x`:

```
x.tolist()
Out[221]: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

To get your `countOf1` to work you'll need to do it for `x.tolist()[0]`. This will give you:

```
x.tolist()[0].count(1)
Out[223]: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a numpy matrix is like a list of lists. Even though you only created one row vector, numpy writes it with 2 brackets ([[0,1,2,3,4...,11]]). So when you changed it to a list with tolist(), you created a list within a list. Since the list within the list != 1, the count is 0.